# Find out how much GPU memory is being used DirectX 11

Tags: c++, directx, gpu, direct3d, directx-11

I was wondering if there was any way to query or keep track of the total video memory I am using in my Direct3D 11 C++ app? I know how to query the GPU for the total available memory but I want to keep a track of how much of it I am using. Is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of profilers out there. If you just need GPU memory over time by application, possibly the easiest is good old [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx). After installing it, double click your application and select the GPU graph.

Here's an image of me hammering on my app:
[image]

If you find yourself needing more data, [NVidia Nsight](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-nsight-visual-studio-edition) is nothing short of amazing.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will check out process explorer. I have tried NSight but I cannot get it to work on my setup, even though I should be able to. Thread on Nvidia dev forums is here: https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/621692/nsight-visual-studio-edition/perfkit-compatibility-with-geforce-gt-640m-le/

Comment: it seems process explorer can query it withou any additional dependencies. so it should be possible to do this also programmatically.